# MYSQL UPDATE with a value in SELECT to a multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mybatis

Im new in MySQL
Implemtation: Im trying to Update in MYSQL where the value of `cd.money_balance - SUM(lp.product_price)` will update it to the column of `cd.money_balance`
but base in my research and Update with combination of SELECT is the solution.
But im having issue in `TEST3` compilation of query

`Test1`
This is working when manual update the value

```
UPDATE 
tbclientdetails cd
LEFT JOIN 
tbclientlogin cl
ON cl.client_login_id = cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN
tbpurchasedetails pd
ON  pd.client_purchase_id = cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN 
tblazardoproduct lp
ON lp.product_id = pd.client_product_purchase_id
SET cd.money_balance =  500
WHERE cd.client_email = "justin@gmail.com";
```

`Test2`
This wont work since `SUM(lp.product_price)` can be use in SELECT

```
UPDATE 
tbclientdetails cd
LEFT JOIN 
tbclientlogin cl
ON cl.client_login_id = cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN
tbpurchasedetails pd
ON  pd.client_purchase_id = cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN 
tblazardoproduct lp
ON lp.product_id = pd.client_product_purchase_id
SET cd.money_balance =  cd.money_balance - SUM(lp.product_price)
WHERE cd.client_email = "justin@gmail.com";
```

`Test3`
Update with select but has error
`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'total.product_id' in 'on clause'`
`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'lp.product_id' in 'on clause'`
i tried `total.product_id` and `lp.product_id`

```
UPDATE
tbclientdetails cd
LEFT JOIN 
tbclientlogin cl
ON cl.client_login_id = cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN
tbpurchasedetails pd
ON  pd.client_purchase_id = cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN( SELECT  SUM(lp.product_price) AS totalprice
           FROM tblazardoproduct lp
           GROUP BY lp.product_id
         )AS total
ON total.product_id = pd.client_product_purchase_id
SET cd.money_balance = cd.money_balance - total.totalprice
WHERE cd.client_email = "justin@gmail.com"
```

Comment: In Test3 you forgot to SELECT the product_id (`SELECT product_id, SUM(product_price) AS totalprice ...`).

Comment: It works, i see, now i understand how update with select work. thanks @Mihe

Comment: and use single quotes for strings, mysql allows both still it is better to follow the standard